# creating android apps

Tags: c#, android

Im a C# developer (sarted a few months ago) and I always been an android fanatic. Now, I know that android apps are developed in java. Since java and c# are quite similar, Im wondering if I can develop android apps using c#, or do I have to learn java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create Android apps via. C# - I think the best thing to look into in your case would be [Mono](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) for android.

Comment: What about something with a reasonable licensing situation?

Comment: @DessixMachina There is a free package available, of course it has less stuff available with it but you can still do many things.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind paying the $400 dollars for the license, Unity3D is a really easy way of making mobile apps for the android (and the iphone at the same time if you own a mac). But of course the android license isn't free.

Coding games in Unity3D is fairly simple in my experience, so if you're new to programming you shouldn't have too much trouble.

Comment: Looks very nice. Just have to read more about it though :)